# How to check the default email client programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, email, registry, default

I developing a C# Winforms application which have the send email feature using the mailto: protocol.

There is a problem with our user is that their computer doesn't have any Email Client app installed as well as the Microsoft Store and it make our application crash instead of a pop-up asking user to choose an app to open.

I tried checking the default email client in the registry, but it doesn't work really well because it just doesn't match with the Default email app that I'm setting in the Default App Setting of Windows.

For example: I set the Mailbird as the default Email app in the setting but in the registry "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail", it still shows that the default is the Thunderbird (which I uninstalled a long time ago).

Can you help me check the default Email client that is currently is set in the Default App Setting by using C# code?

Thank you

Comment: No matter what the default is, you should not be crashing. Are you invoking with ShellExecute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one would think that the Client key controls the default but the effective default is the handler of the mailto: protocol.

[MSDN still says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/start-menu-reg?redirectedfrom=MSDN#how-to-register-as-the-default-email-client)

> How to Register as the Default EMail Client
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail can contain zero or more subkeys, one for each registered email application.

Too bad it does not reflect the real world.

A prominent Windows shell team developer [suggests `AssocQueryString`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916173107/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/09/14/10641381.aspx) (change "http" to "mailto").

My personal preference is `IApplicationAssociationRegistration::QueryCurrentDefault(..., AL_EFFECTIVE,...)`

With `AssocQueryString`, be prepared to ignore "OpenWith.exe". With `QueryCurrentDefault`, be prepared to ignore S_OK:"Undecided".

On paper, `AssocQueryString` seems like the better choice but at least for file extensions, `QueryCurrentDefault` is much better at detecting the real default on systems where the ProgId mapping is protected and encrypted.

Detection will never be perfect because the handler could be a shell extension instead and the true default is only known when you actually call `ShellExecute`.